# Twitter API loop through result pages

Tags: php, twitter

Im trying to look my way into all the pages of a search request to the twitter API but it gets stocked:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=%23'.$hashtag.'&result_type=recent&include_entities=true&count=100';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settingsIdea);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest();
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach($json->statuses as $tweet){
  // analyse each tweet
}
while (isset($json->search_metadata->next_results)):
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
  $getfield =  $json->search_metadata->next_results;
  $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
  ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
  ->performRequest();
  $json = json_decode($response);
  foreach($json->statuses as $tweet){
    //analyze each tweet
   }
endwhile;
```

Im trying to use this as the flag:

```
isset($json->search_metadata->next_results)
```

But it doesn't stop the loop. Any ideas of how to loop correctly through all the pages?

**Additional issue:**

```
$json->search_metadata->next_results
```

as the $getfield URL since it converts a '%' for a '25'

Example output of echo $json->search_metadata->next_results;

```
?max_id=XXXXXXXXXX&q=2523hashtag&count=100&include_entities=1&result_type=recent
```

When it should be:

```
?max_id=XXXXXXXXXX&q=%23hashtag&count=100&include_entities=1&result_type=recent
```

Comment: Did you found an answer to this for yourself? Having the same question

Comment: Sadly I didn't, if you get it working please let me know